# C++ Union Array differs in 32/64 bits

Tags: c++, arrays, 64-bit, unions, 32-bit

My code:

```
union FIELD {
    int n;
    char c;
    const char *s;
    FIELD(){}
    FIELD(int v){ n = v; }
    FIELD(char v){ c = v; }
    FIELD(const char* v){ s = v; }
};

struct SF {
    const char* s0;
    char s1;
    int s2;
    const char* s3;
};

int main() {
    printf("sizeof(long) = %ld\n", sizeof(long));
    printf("now is %d bit\n", sizeof(long) == 8?64:32);

    FIELD arrField[] = {
        FIELD("any 8 words 0 mixed"), FIELD('d'), FIELD(251356), FIELD("edcba")
    };
    SF* sf0 = (SF*)&arrField;

    printf("sf0->s0 = %s, ", sf0->s0);
    printf("sf0->s1 = %c, ", sf0->s1);
    printf("sf0->s2 = %d, ", sf0->s2);
    printf("sf0->s3 = %s\n", sf0->s3);
}
```

When I use the default 64-bit execution output:

[image]

I add the compilation parameters in `CMakeLists.txt`:

```
set_target_properties(untitled PROPERTIES COMPILE_FLAGS "-m32" LINK_FLAGS "-m32")
```

It will compile the 32-bit program, then run and output:

[image]

---

My question is, how can I make a 64-bit program have the same output behavior as a 32-bit program?

Comment: You would use fixed width types. `int32_t` instead of `long` etc. You won't be able to affect the `sizeof` pointers though

Comment: You can't.  A pointer in a 32 bit system only needs to worry about 32 bits worth of memory address space.  A pointer in a 64 bit system has to deal with 64 bits of address space.

Comment: This is why unions are a bad idea for type punning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apply `alignas(FIELD)` to every single member variable of `SF`.

Additionally you cannot rely on the size of `long` to tell 64 bit and 32 bit systems appart. Check the size of a pointer to do this. On some 64 bit systems `long` is 32 bit. This is the case for my system for example.

Furthermore `%ld` requires a `long` parameter, but the `sizeof` operator yields `size_t` which is unsigned in addition to not necesarily matching `long` in size. You need to add a cast there to be safe (or just go with `std::cout` which automatically chooses the correct conversion based on the second operand of the `<<` operator).

```
union FIELD {
    int n;
    char c;
    const char* s;
    FIELD() {}
    FIELD(int v) { n = v; }
    FIELD(char v) { c = v; }
    FIELD(const char* v) { s = v; }
};

struct SF {
    alignas(FIELD) const char* s0;
    alignas(FIELD) char s1;
    alignas(FIELD) int s2;
    alignas(FIELD) const char* s3;
};

int main() {
    printf("sizeof(long) = %ld\n", static_cast<long>(sizeof(long)));
    printf("now is %d bit\n", static_cast<int>(sizeof(void*)) * 8);

    FIELD arrField[] = {
        FIELD("any 8 words 0 mixed"), FIELD('d'), FIELD(251356), FIELD("edcba")
    };
    SF* sf0 = (SF*)&arrField;

    printf("sf0->s0 = %s, ", sf0->s0);
    printf("sf0->s1 = %c, ", sf0->s1);
    printf("sf0->s2 = %d, ", sf0->s2);
    printf("sf0->s3 = %s\n", sf0->s3);
}
```

Comment: [@fabian](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2991525/fabian) I am porting the old code of 32-bit system to 64-bit system. You solved the difficulties I encountered in my work, and thank you for correcting me about 64-bit judgment in the program. grateful! :)